# Toggle between two classes with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I really tried many things on this on but did not find a proper solution, I need to toggle between too classes with animation seems very simple. This should change the height of an element from nothing to something. It works with toggleClass function but not smooth

```
 $el.not(':eq(0)').toggleClass(class2 + ' ' + 'col-md-8');
```

class2 can be 'col-md-12' or 'hidden'.

PS

these things did not work
  $el.not(':eq(0)').toggleClass(class2 + ' ' + 'col-md-8', 1000);

also .slideToggle() is not working as I want cause it doesn't take two classes.

Thanks heaps

Comment: i suggest  OP include all relevant code or create snippet

Comment: can you use jquery-ui toggleClass? it has a duration option. https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Given is looks like you are just trying to show/hide, why not just do `$el.not(':eq(0)').toggle('fast')`